# Changing font color in java script

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint

```
$("table[class='ms-listviewtable'] td:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "red");
```

I am currently using that to change the background color of a column in SharePoint. Cna some one tell me how to change the font color?

I tried

```
.css("font-color", "red");
```

and

```
css("text-color", "red");
```

Both did not work

Answer (score 2):

The correct css property for coloring the text on an element is `color`.

So in your case: `.css("color", "red");`

Comment: Always `color` for changing text color. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/whdmyz6p/...

Comment: if you make the text red, make sure the background color isn-t red too!!

Comment: I see that to be working there but my implementation of this java script in SharePoint doesn't work. The background color worked but the font color is not working. I made sure the background color is not red

Comment: @user1760174 If this didn't work for you, your issue is with javascript not the css -- lots of reasons javascript may not work properly in SharePoint but we would need to see more of your code

Answer (score 0):

Color is the correct property to change the text color. you can test by running the following in your browsers console.

```
$("p").css("color", "red");
```

see how the text changes color on this page.

If it is not working it is more likely an issue with your selectors. Also you can easily simplify your other selector by doing the following

```
$("table.ms-listviewtable td:nth-child(2)")
```

Comment: On a browser it is working fine. But I am not sure why it doesn't work in SharePoint if the background color worked. I tried simplifying the selector but still no luck

Comment: FYI, I am implementing this script on a .aspx page if that makes any difference.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the actual code. The selector you are using and the element you are trying to select. There is the possibility that other javascript is writing the color (which can be confirmed by looking at your styles in your dev tools) or that there is an error or conditional that is preventing this line from being executed. Have you checked your console for errors? If there are none, and you are sure your selector is right, try spitting out a console.log just above this line to confirm that it is being reached.

Comment: Also make sure that your css (especially an ID) is specifying a text color. Without a 'stronger' css specification your text will not change. Find ANY mention of text color in your css/scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This method can take either a property name and value as separate parameters, or a single object of key-value pairs.

So you can use either `.css('color','#FF0000');` or `.css({'color':'#FF0000'});`